# Reference an owner class from inside one of its callable attributes

Tags: python, descriptor, callable

I want to assign a callable class as a function on another class, and then reference the owner class from the owned function:

```
class DoIt(object):

    def __call__(self):
        print "%s did it" % self.name

class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    doSomething = DoIt()


doer = Doer("Bob")
doer.doSomething()
```

In the code above, I want the `doSomething()` function to print "Bob did it", but with this code I'll get a

> AttributeError: 'DoIt' object has no attribute 'name'

Because self references the DoIt instance, not the Doer instance. Is it possible to reference the Doer instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class DoIt(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def done():
            print "%s did it" % instance.name
        return done

class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    doSomething = DoIt()


doer = Doer("Bob")
doer.doSomething()
```

---

**Explanation:** *(This is the asker explaining this answer as best he can)*

Python offers you descriptor classes, which are classes that act as attributes (in contrast to attributes as instance variables or properties). The `__get__` method of a descriptor class dictates what's returned when that class is assigned and accessed as an attribute on another class. And `__get__` lets you access both the owning instance and owning class (See method signature).

By having `__get__` return a function, you essentially create a callable that has access to its owner.

For more on descriptors, see [Attributes, Properties and Descriptors- Building Skills in Python](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/book/python-2.6/html/p03/p03c05_properties.html)

Comment: I *knew* Python would deliver- thanks for forcing me to understand descriptors. (I inserted my own explanation into your answer, based on my understanding)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
class DoIt(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __call__(self):
        print "%s did it" % self.obj.name

class Doer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.doSomething = DoIt(self)

doer = Doer("Bob")
doer.doSomething()    # prints 'Bob did it'
```

Comment: ... or just pass the `name` to the `DoIt` initializer, but +1.

Comment: @larsmans - That would work for this particular example, but OP was asking how to reference the owner class so that is how I approached the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely another example for Ignacio's answer- I wanted to show the same concept when a parameter is required for the "callable".

```
class DoIt(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        def done(what):
            print "%s did something %s" % (instance.name, what)
        return done

class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    doSomething = DoIt()

doer = Doer("Bob")
doer.doSomething("cool")
```

prints:

> Bob did something cool